# How to find the length of the string which also contains string terminating character in between. Example: ABC\0ABC

Tags: c++, c

How to find the length of the string which also contains string terminating character in between. Example: ABC\0ABC. Is there any inbuilt function present which returns the length?

If the Input string is: ABC\0ABC
Output: 8

Comment: What type of string? c-string(null terminated char*), std::string?

Comment: In what kind of variables are you storing this value ? a `std::string` or a `char *` ? The answer will depend on this.

Comment: I am storing this string in char*.  But i would appreciate if you can throw some light by considering both the ways. Thanks

Comment: If you are storing the string in a char* then there is no answer. That string is technically "ABC", not "ABC/0ABC".

Comment: When you put the `\0` in there, do you mean it contains a backslash followed by a zero? Or do you mean it contains an actual zero byte? If the former, what's the problem with `strlen`? If the latter, how do you get 8? A, B, C, \0, A, B, C -> 7.

Comment: char* uses \0 to mark where the string ends, so if you have one in the middle of the string, there's no way for it to determine whether or not you want it to be part of the string.

Comment: Ok....what i understood is that if you are storing ABC\0ABC in a char* then you cant  solve it.  So, what is the other way to solve this problem? I can hold the aforesaid string in anything. All i want is that the length should come correctly.

Comment: @user1168582: There is no general solution. If someone is passing you a `char*` that contains '\0' characters, then they should be courteous enough to pass you the *length* of that string too. If they don't, then I would strongly suggest not using their code. If that's not possible, then go find the programmer and make them provide a length. If that's not possible either, then fix the code so that it will provide a length yourself. And if none of *that* is possible... you're screwed. Note that any file loading API *will* give you a length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the end of a C-style string is only detectable because it ends in a `'\0'` character, what you're asking isn't solvable in a general way.  If, like in your example, you know there's exactly one `'\0'` character in the string, then you can simply do:

```
x =  strlen(string);             // length of string before the first '\0'
x += strlen(string + x + 1) + 1; // plus the length of the string after
                                 // the first '\0' plus the '\0' itself.
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second strlen be strlen(string + x +1)?

Comment: What if I dont know the number of times '\0' going to come in my string?

Comment: Then you're out of luck.  Why do you have null characters in your string in the first place?

Comment: @user1168582: Then your options boil down to either being told what the length is or having no idea what the length is. You cannot *magic* that length into existence. It will either happen by convention (first '\0' character) or you will be given a length. That's why C++ programers tend to use `std::string` or some actual string container class. Most of those don't care about `\0` characters.

Comment: I am not able to understand how the following statement is working: x += strlen(string + x + 1) + 1;

Comment: I wrote a comment that explains it.  What's the problem?

Comment: The string should terminate with two consecutive null-characters to indicate end.